# A single threaded client/server in C# with file upload, download

Tags: c#, client-server, distributed-system

So I'm creating a basic single threaded file server that supports 4 different operations, like upload, download, delete and rename.

I'm trying to implement local server, where client and server both uses different port to communicate. Client is able to browse local file and upload it to the server, and able to download file from server.

What I don't know is how to implement this browse function and how to upload/download file from the server. I can implement simple message passing program between client/server.